# If the array value is equal to something do some functions Android

Tags: java, android

First of all, I would like to inform the question is not a duplicate.

The problem is, In my Android project I have included a `Gridview` which is targeting an Activity(PDF Viewer Activity). All the Grid items are made for opening PDF files. But, I need one activity to open another Activity which has more categories. 
I have tried the following codes:

```
@Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               if(Arrays.asList(name).equals("Categories")){
                   Intent ij = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quran.class);
                   startActivity(ij);
               }
               else{

               Intent ij = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PdfView.class);
               ij.putExtra("furl", "fl/" + file[position]);
               ij.putExtra("pagenm", pagenum[position]);
               startActivity(ij);
               }
           }
```

Also, tried some other codes like `if(name.conatains)`,etc. It works but the rule is applied to all the remaining items, becuase the rule is just `conatins`. Actually the one I need is like:

```
if(name.value=="category"){
           *//Open the category activity*
}
else{
           *//Open the PDF Viewer Acivity*
}
```

`name` is an Array of PDF titles.

Comment: Add your `name` datatype and implementation

Comment: Its an array of PDF file names.

Comment: can you post full code of this file

Comment: Use ``if(Arrays.asList(name).contains("Categories")){``

Comment: what is name in this line??? Arrays.asList(name).equals("Categories")

Comment: i think it should be Arrays.get(position).getName.equals("Categories").
first put name against each item and the use it like above

Comment: @MuhmmadUmair ```Arrays.get...``` shows *Cannot resolve method ```get()```*

Comment: `Arrays.asList(name).equals("Categories")` is obviously not going to work. `Array.asList()` returns `List` while `"Categories"` is a `String`. You've made a simple type error, which means this question, unfortunately, **is** a duplicate.

Comment: @sasikumar Please check the code here https://codeshare.io/5vWgDy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
Arrays.asList(name).contains("Categories")
```

instead of

```
Arrays.asList(name).equals("Categories")
```

**Or** if you create the adapter with `name` array then you can directly check with `position` like below:

```
name[position].equals("Categories")
```

Comment: The code works, but it applies to all the items in the ```Gridview```. Because the rule you mentioned here is applying to all the items.

Comment: Then try `name[position].contains("Categories")` or `name[position].equals("Categories")`. Actually it's impossible to identify if you don't reveal code

Comment: @FathahKodag, Did you try this?